# Build List recursively from match result in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, and so am just experimenting.  The following code prints out the names of all files recursively under D:\Downloads:

```
import java.io.File

object Run {
  def main (args: Array[String]){
    //read each file
    val f = new File("""D:\Downloads""");
    listFiles(f)
  }

  def listFiles(f: Any): Unit= f match{
    case f:File if f.isDirectory => f.listFiles().deep.foreach(listFiles(_))
    case f:File if f.isFile => println(f.getName)
    case _ => Unit
  }
}
```

This works.  Now, I would like listFiles to build up a List of Strings and return that.  This is what I have done:

```
  def listFiles(f: Any): List[String] = f match{
    case f:File if f.isDirectory => f.listFiles().foreach(listFiles(_))
    case f:File if f.isFile => List(f.getName)
    case _ => Nil
  }
```

When f is a directory, foreach should recursively call listFiles and a List will be returned.  How can I concatenate all of these arrays together and return them?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate them together as one string or one list?

Comment: @barnesjd - I want them concatenated as one list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working from your approach, use `flatMap`:

```
def listFiles(f: Any): List[String] = f match{
  case f:File if f.isDirectory => f.listFiles().toList.flatMap(listFiles(_))
  case f:File if f.isFile => List(f.getName)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Comment: Thank-you, this is what I was looking for.  I found that it can be made a little bit better looking by dropping the () after listFiles as this is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

The following can probably be improved upon, but it should be an acceptable starting point:

```
def listFiles(f: File) = {
  def run(f: File, acc: List[File]): List[File] =
    if(f.isFile) f :: acc
    else         f.listFiles.foldLeft(acc) {(l, f) => run(f, l)}

  run(f, Nil)
}
```

Comment: Going to upvote this for having what appears to be the fastest implementation, at least by a bit (on my computer).

Comment: Do note that while I'm quite happy with my solution, I feel that @barnesjd's use of `flatmap` probably makes more sense than `foldLeft`...

Comment: He got a +1 as well. They're both valid solutions for different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `flatmap` on the list of files, but because I prefer how for-comprehensions look, here:

```
 def listFiles(f: Any): List[String] = f match {
   case d: File if d.isDirectory => for {
      file <- d.listFiles.toList
      fileName <- listFiles(file)
      } yield fileName

   case f: File if f.isFile => List(f.getName)
   case _ => Nil
 }
```

On a different note, you should go for stronger type-safety and define the method as :

```
 def listFiles(f:File): List[String]
```

This way it can only be called with `File` arguments and you can catch more errors at compile time.

Comment: I went for f:Any because it wouldn't compile on a previous version that I made.  I've just tried moving to f:File and this works great - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting intrigued by this question when trying out various implementations. Most of them took over a second on my computer to list out a fairly nested directory with a total of approximately 4500 files.

I wrote an implementation using Stream, for instances where you might not need *all* the files all at once. It seems to perform about as well as the List implementations when you forcibly get every file.

```
import java.io.File

def listFiles(f : File): Stream[File] = {
  def streamFiles(fs : List[File]): Stream[File] = fs match {
    case x::xs => x match {
      case x if x.isDirectory => streamFiles(x.listFiles.toList) #::: streamFiles(xs)
      case x if x.isFile      => x #:: streamFiles(xs) 
    }
    case Nil    => Stream.empty
  }

  if (f.isDirectory)
    streamFiles(f.listFiles.toList)
  else
    f #:: Stream.empty
}
```

This will yield your list of files lazily.